# Is it acceptable to initialize the parent class from within the subclass __init__()?

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass

Is it good practice to initialize a parent class from within the subclass, so that the parent class attributes are available to the created subclass instance?
Are there alternatives or best practices in doing so?

As an example:

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name, weight, cute=False, image=None):
        #Instantiation attributes
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight
        self.cute = cute
        self.image = image
        #Attributes common to all animals
        self.extinct = False
    def get_animal_stats(self):
        print arbitrary_animal_stat

class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name, weight):
        Animal.__init__(self, name, weight, cute=True, image="dog.com")
        #Additional attributes unique to dogs
        self.number_legs = 4
        self.teeth = True
    def make_noise(self):
        print "Bark!"
```

As I understand it, without initializing the parent class during the subclass initialization, the subclass object only has access to its own attributes (ie. number_legs and teeth, and make_noise) and not the parent classes attributes or methods (ie. extinct, and get_animal_stats).

I find myself writing many small classes for predefined objects but have to initialize the parent with the child.  In this way, I can create a simple Animal on the fly or create a more descriptive Animal through the Dog subclass.

What is the proper way to access Parent attributes and methods from the subclass instance?  Am I misunderstanding the use of subclasses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only is it acceptable, you should almost always call the parent class's constructor. The only reason you would not do so is if you

1. are absolutely sure that there will never be any initialization code defined in the parent class that is necessary for the object to function and
2. You want to explicitly override the parent class's initialization behavior.

With new style classes (those that inherit from object), it is better to use `super()` as it takes care of resolution order in cases of multiple inheritance. In Python 2.7, use:

```
class ParentFooA(GrandparentFoo):
    def __init__(self):
        some_important_initialization_code()

class ChildFoo(ParentFoo):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ChildFoo, self).__init__()
```

Note that another nice property is that you don't have to use the name `ParentFoo` anywhere in `ChildFoo` *except* when you define inheritance (for instance, in the line `class ChildFoo(...)`). It also works for other methods:

```
class ChildFoo(ParentFoo):
    ...
    def do_buzz(self):
        super(ChildFoo, self).do_buzz()
```

`super()` does *not* work for old-style classes (that is, classes that don't inherit from `object`).
This means that with much of the standard library, you still have to call the parent class's constructor explicitly. So in this case:

```
class OldStyleParent:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
```

You would have to call `OldStyleParent.__init__()` explicitly in `__init__()`.

In Python 3, `super`'s syntax is simply:

```
class ChildFooInPython3(ParentFoo):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

Comment: Great Answer!  I have a few clarifying questions:  When would you opt for 1.?  If you are certain there is no initializing code in the parent class necessary for the child to function, should the child be subclassed in the first place?  Super() is good to know about.  From your answer, I understand it to be used for multiple inheritance, but isnt it better to be explicit about what parent class you instantiate (with regards to the inheritance stack)?

Comment: `super()` automatically adapts to changes in inheritance structure, allowing you to write your child class without (too much) knowledge about it's parent class(es). In Python, inheritance stacks need not be linear, `super()` (when used correctly and consistently) helps to smooth out cases of multiple inheritance.

Comment: As for 1, I've used classes as "mix-ins" which provide user-defined classes with some additional functionality. These "mix-ins" mostly consisted of staticmethods and didn't really need any initialization. I've also used abstract base classes to enforce Java style "interfaces". These classes exist so that their methods will be overridden and usually don't need any initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with that, although you might want to use super():

```
super(Dog, self).__init__...
```

Or in Python 3:

```
super().__init__...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name, weight):
        super(Dog, self).__init__(name, weight, cute=True, image="dog.com")
        #Additional attributes unique to dogs
        self.number_legs = 4
        self.teeth = True
    def make_noise(self):
        print "Bark!"
```